# Insert XML node after every element by tag

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xml and I want to insert a `<separatorItem/>` after every `</subMenu>` that has a `<scriptItem/>` after it.

Or in other words you could rephrase as I want to insert a `<separatorItem/>` at every level of the xml hierarchy after the last `<subMenu>` that contains more elements after it, within the same level.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mainMenu>
    <menuBar>
        <subMenu>
            <label>Main</label>
            <subMenu>
                <label>Sub Menu</label>
                <subMenu>
                    <label>Sub-Sub Menu</label>
                    <scriptItem>
                        <label>Email</label>
                    </scriptItem>
                </subMenu>
                <scriptItem>
                    <label>Manager</label>
                </scriptItem>
            </subMenu>
            <subMenu>
                <label>Dev</label>
                <scriptItem>
                    <label>Dialog</label>
                </scriptItem>
            </subMenu>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Sample</label>
            </scriptItem>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Home</label>
            </scriptItem>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Browser</label>
            </scriptItem>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Check</label>
            </scriptItem>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Open</label>
            </scriptItem>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Close</label>
            </scriptItem>
        </subMenu>
    </menuBar>
</mainMenu>
```

starting code

```py
import os
import re
import sys
import logging
import xml.dom.minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


fp = os.path.abspath('elementTree.xml')
tree = ET.parse(fp)
root = tree.getroot()

# insert separator after every subMenu that's followed by a scriptItem
# parent = None
# for el in root.iter():
    # parent = root # find correct subMenu to place sep after
    # sep = ET.SubElement(parent, 'separatorItem')
sep = ET.Element('separatorItem')
root.insert(1, sep)


xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, encoding='UTF-8', method="xml")
xmlObj = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xmlstr)
xmlstr = xmlObj.toprettyxml(encoding='UTF-8')

menuFilepath = os.path.abspath('updated.xml')
with open(menuFilepath, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(xmlstr)
```

The end goal looking like this...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mainMenu>
    <menuBar>
        <subMenu>
            <label>Main</label>
            <subMenu>
                <label>Sub Menu</label>
                <subMenu>
                    <label>Sub-Sub Menu</label>
                    <scriptItem>
                        <label>Email</label>
                    </scriptItem>
                </subMenu>
                <separatorItem/> <!-- INSERTED !-->
                <scriptItem>
                    <label>Manager</label>
                </scriptItem>
            </subMenu>
            <subMenu>
                <label>Dev</label>
                <scriptItem>
                    <label>Dialog</label>
                </scriptItem>
            </subMenu>
            <separatorItem/> <!-- INSERTED !-->
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Sample</label>
            </scriptItem>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Home</label>
            </scriptItem>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Browser</label>
            </scriptItem>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Check</label>
            </scriptItem>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Open</label>
            </scriptItem>
            <scriptItem>
                <label>Close</label>
            </scriptItem>
        </subMenu>
    </menuBar>
</mainMenu>
```

Comment: It is a task for XSLT transformation

Answer (score 0):

I would use lxml instead, due to its better xpath support:

```
from lxml import etree as etree
menus = """[your xml above]"""

doc = etree.fromstring(menus.encode())
targets = doc.xpath('//subMenu[not(.//subMenu)][./scriptItem]')
for target in targets:
    sep = etree.fromstring("""<separatorItem/>""".encode())
    target.addnext(sep)       

print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

The output should be what you're looking for.